# Replace words in html element multiple times

Tags: jquery

I have this set of input fields that must replace each token with its value in .confirm. I want to be able to replace it each time I click on .btn. But it only works with the last input field.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e16c289j/1/)

html

```
<div class="inputs">
    <input class="input-1 anotherclass" type="text"> <br>
    <input class="input-2 anotherclass" type="text"><br>
    <input class="input-3 anotherclass" type="text"> <br>
    <input class="input-4 anotherclass" type="text">
</div>

<div class="confirm">
    {input-1} <br>
    {input-2} <br>
    {input-3} <br>
    {input-4} 
</div>

<button class="btn">edit</button>
```

js

```
var confirmCopy = $(".confirm").data("my-attr", $(".confirm").html());

$(".btn").on("click", function() {

    var confirm = $(".confirm");

    $("[class*=input-]").each(function(){

        var inputThis = $(this);

        var className = $.grep(this.className.split(" "), function(v, i){

            return v.indexOf('input-') === 0;

        }).join();

       confirm.html(confirmCopy.data("my-attr").replace("{"+className+"}", inputThis.val()));
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that in every iteration of the `each` loop, you start your replace from the *confirmCopy* data, instead of accumulating the results.

Here is a correction:

```js
var confirmCopy = $(".confirm").data("my-attr", $(".confirm").html());
$(".btn").on("click", function() {
    var confirm = $(".confirm");
    var s = confirmCopy.data("my-attr");
    $("[class*=input-]").each(function(){
        var inputThis = $(this);
        var className = $.grep(this.className.split(" "), function(v, i){
            return v.indexOf('input-') === 0;
        }).join();
        s = s.replace("{"+className+"}", inputThis.val());
    });
    confirm.html(s);
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inputs">
    <input class="input-1 anotherclass" type="text"> <br>
    <input class="input-2 anotherclass" type="text"><br>
    <input class="input-3 anotherclass" type="text"> <br>
    <input class="input-4 anotherclass" type="text">
</div>

<div class="confirm">
    {input-1} <br>
    {input-2} <br>
    {input-3} <br>
    {input-4} 
</div>

<button class="btn">edit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here

```
confirm.html(confirmCopy.data("my-attr").replace("{"+className+"}", inputThis.val()));
```

You are using same old template to update div. `confirmCopy.data("my-attr")`

After every replace you should update var `confirmCopy`

This will work perfect.

$( document ).ready(function() {
     var confirmCopy = $(".confirm").data("my-attr",$(".confirm").html());

```
 $(".btn").on("click", function() {
   var confirm = $(".confirm");
   var temp = confirmCopy.data("my-attr");
   $("[class*=input-]").each(function(){
     var inputThis = $(this);


    var className = $.grep(this.className.split(" "), function(v, i){
    return v.indexOf('input-') === 0;
      }).join();

    temp = temp.replace("{"+className+"}", inputThis.val());

    confirm.html(temp);

   });
 });
});
```

Comment: huh? The `{}` placeholders will be lost if you do that

Comment: Try running this. btw which placeholders?

Comment: The placeholders stored in `$(".confirm").data("my-attr")`. You are removing them

Comment: Change inputs and click button more than once...it fails

Comment: You are right. @charlietfl Thanks :) Let me use a helper var.